# How to show custom Splash Screen Spinner (i.e spinner with white color) in iOS phonegap app?

Tags: iphone, ios, cordova

Is it possible to change default Splash Screen Spinner color to white ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this for for Spinner

[hzactivityindicatorview](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/hzactivityindicatorview)

Comment: Thanks @SAMIR : I will try this source code https://github.com/hezi/HZActivityIndicatorView

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to built an custom view with White Activity indicator  and launch it when you application launches for particular time. Please find the link i think it will help [here](http://nullpointr.wordpress.com/2012/02/19/iphone-dev-how-to-implement-a-splash-screen/)